# Problems after Extreme Tux Racer

Tags: debian-wheezy

After a fresh install of Debian Wheezy 7.6 on my Optiplex 745, all seems to go well.  After running Extreme Tux Racer, however, my screen cannot display more that 800x600.  The only way I can fix this is to add nomodesetting to grub.  But after doing this, I can only run gnome classic.  Is there a way to return to previous display setting (as it was before I ran Extreme Tux Racer)?